# Click <span>? element or button without name or get submit to work

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I've been poking around the internet at large cobbling together some VBA code to try to interact with some web pages (and eventually scrape).

I have some decent knowledge of VB and programming, but the internet end of things is pretty new to me, especially the syntax of commands, so I'm leveraging things from the internet.

I have one that's working,

http://snowload.atcouncil.org/

This I can fill in and get to submit with a

```
doc.getelementsbyId("coordinate_address").value = range("City").value _ 
& ", " & range("State").value 
doc.getelementsbyId("btn-submit").click
```

then wait it out until readystate =4 , etc.

The one I can't get to work is here.

http://windspeed.atcouncil.org/

This one seems to use a  object that I can't figure out how to click. It doesn't seem to have a name, and Id, etc.

If I use conventional 'submit' on the windspeed page, (loosely using that term), the page loads, but it comes out blank. Like I'm not using the syntax correctly, or not passing a variable/searchform somehow.

```
ie.document.all.item("submit").click
```

This 'works' but it produces a blank page with the east coast of africa and no data.

In the immediate/console of the browser, after I click, say, the Hawaii button, it works with document.searchform.submit()

If I try that in code, it doesn't work. (The Immediate window in the VBA editor thows me a "expected: =" error,

The object I am trying to click is in the web site code.....

```
<span>
 <input type="submit" value="Get Windspeed" onclick="valbutton(searchform); return false;">
<span>
```

I've tried a lot of techniques poached from the internet, but no success yet. (looping over elements using getelementsbyclassname "span", but it either doesn't find the one with value ="Get Windspeed", or it doesn't find it at all.

somehow triggering the valbutton (that's a subroutine/function on the page) seems like a workaround... but VBA seems to want different syntax than the console on the web page and it's doing the same kind of "expected: =" syntax error when I try that approach.

I suspect normal submit would work, but I'm somehow not passing the filled out page and am sending a blank to the submit/get?

I also notice that if you are on the page, type in an address, and hit enter, it runs that "find" button I can't figure out (same thing, no name or ID obvious, it's a button....), and if you hit enter after it reloads, then it somehow by default hits that 'get windspeed' button, which suggests to me they are both submit buttons in a way.

Thanks for reading, I appreciate any thoughts on the matter. I am trying to get this to get all the data input and get the results without adding anything beyond VBA (i.e. jscript or vbscript or other things,)

-Brian

Comment: Please keep your stackoverflow post down to one question which contains reproducible code.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply submit the form after setting the .Value of the inputs.

```
doc.getelementsbyId("searchform").submit
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to adapt this (despite the claim this doesn't work in IE11..., maybe I'm not using 11...Is eleven Miscrosoft Edge?)

https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/344297-need-visual-basic-applications-code-execute-javascript.html

```
IE.Document.parentWindow.execScript "CheckAndSubmit(document.frmViewMyAcct);"
```

that allowed me to mimic hitting the button or hitting submit and somehow got around the 'no information / resulting page is blank' issue. The onclick event has a javascript routine attached to it, so I just copied that syntax.

Thanks for the help, it got me started on the solution.

Regards,
Brian